# how to add environment variable in linux for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, environment-variables

i need to set an environment variable for the rails app to use

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=9941144eb255ff0ffecasdlkjqweqwelkjasdlkjasd
```

the config settings for production is as shown below

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

how can i set the environment variable using the linux command

```
export VARNAME="my value"
```

I tried to set the variable but looks like it needs to be for the right user. Sorry i am not an expert in linux. 
I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by *but looks like it needs to be for the right user*? BTW `export VARNAME="my value"` works.

Comment: i am using ubuntu.

Comment: @Pavan does that command need to be run as root user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export VARNAME="my value"
```

Well the above works for your current terminal session. After this command, all the subsequent commands can access this variable. Try running this:

```
echo $VARNAME
```

It will print the value `my value` in the console. If you want this behaviour to be persisted, you need to place the `export` command in your OS' config file (`~/.bashrc` in case of Ubuntu).

After editing this file, either restart your terminal, or run this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will reload the file in your current terminal session. Alternatively, you can try running your Rails server (or a rake command) as follows:

```
VARNAME="my value" rails s
```

Comment: thanks i even have it in .bashrc file but seems like the rails server is running on another account. Should it be added to root user?

Comment: @kofhearts - `.bashrc` is a user dependent file. If the server runs from different account, it should be set on that account's `.bashrc` file.

Comment: how do you find which user the rails server in production runs under?

Comment: @kofhearts - If this is running from a root level account, you can never know. Try running `ps aux | grep rails`. It shows the account from which the Rails server is running.

Comment: it is running as deploy user

Comment: so does this mean i need to put the export in .bashrc file of deploy user?

Comment: @kofhearts - Yes, absolutely!

Comment: thanks that did it. ok i forgot that i used deploy user for capistrano deployment. so this means i need to put the export in the .bashrc file for the created deploy user. also i put the export not at the end but before the  #if not running interactively, dont do anything and finally it WORKED!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your local development I suggest you to use dotenv (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or figaro (https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and follow the README you find in the gem itself. This gives you much more flexibility than using directly environment variables because you set them only for this specific project and each project can have different of them.

You need to have either a `.env` file or a `application.yml` file where you will define your environment variables.

Remember to not commit or push this file to your repository because it contains sensible information!

When you will deploy to production you can use real environment variables or use admin panel control (on Heroku for example)

Comment: how do you set environment variable in production for the app?

Comment: this depends on where you are deploying the app. You can use .env or application.yml also in production if you want.

Comment: Here is how you do it on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: sorry i am using a vps not heroku. i need the linux command to set the env variable.

Comment: as written in my answer I strongly suggest you to use either `dotenv` or `figaro`.